# It's best practice to use nvm or the node form the package manager?

Tags: node.js, fedora, nvm, dnf

I use nodejs which I install using nvm on Debian distro before however I recently change my distro for fedora to do development work, now I know that fedora is a fast moving distro, so it come with very recent version of software and in my case recent node version.I was wondering, what do you use to install node the package manager dnf or the nvm ? Thank you.

Comment: `nvm` or similar libraries help us to manage multiple versions and easy to upgrade and downgrade, I would like to recommend you to use `nvm` instead of Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Using nvm instead of the package manager of any Linux distribution adds compatibility between different Linux distributions and even MacOS and Windows. In general, it is best to use nvm.